# jQuery data() only get first data value

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="myClass" data-info="35">
    <div class="box-red"></div>
</div>

<div class="myClass" data-info="51">
    <div class="box-blue"></div>
</div>

<div class="myClass" data-info="81">
    <div class="box-black"></div>
</div>



[class^="box"]{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
}
.box-red{
    background-color: red;
}
.box-blue{
    background-color: blue;
}
.box-black{
    background-color: black;
}


console.log($('.myClass'))

<div class=​"myClass" data-info=​"35">​…​</div>​, 
<div class=​"myClass" data-info=​"51">​…​</div>​, 
<div class=​"myClass" data-info=​"81">​…​</div>​
```

When I do `console.log($('.myClass').data('info');)` I get only 35

How can I get all values? do I have to use `each`? and `each` is the only way? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.each`

```
$.each($('.myClass'),function(){
    console.log($(this).data('info'));
});
```